# Binary Search Tree Confusion (best-case)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am currently studying for an exam and one of the questions I am confused about is:

**Give 5 orderings of the key A X C S E R H that, when inserted into an initiall empty BST, produce the best-case tree. Assume the lexicographical/alphabetical ordering.**

The answer to this is provided as:

Here are some possible oderings...

H C A E S R X

H C A E S X R

H C E A S R X

H C E A S X R

H C E S A R X

I was wondering if someone can give me some clarification to how 'H' would take on the root node? From my current understanding I assumed 'A' would be the root. I think I need some clarification on how to get to the best-case tree of a BST. If someone could help me understand this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It might be too chatty, but I am just curious - in what institute is that question given in exams?

Comment: Is it possible that you should be balancing your BST? That might make H the root

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first entry will be your root. After that, anything that comes BEFORE your root (alphabetically in this case) will go to the left; AFTER will go to the right.

Each of those produces a tree that can be traced from the bottom left to the bottom right in alphabetical order.

[image]

As you can see this produces a tree which can be read bottom left up towards the root (exploring each branch from the parent before continuing upwards) to create an alphabetic sequence

Comment: +1 It's hard to picture the tree when it is writen in a straight line HCAESRX etc, this had me muddled. Nice easy answer!

Answer (score 3):

If A were the root node, then all of the nodes would be on it's right, and then you wouldn't have the advantage of a tree, you would have something that's more similar to a linked list. For a tree to be a best-case tree, you want the number of nodes left and right from the root node to be a similar number, that's how the depth of the tree will be smaller, and you will get better performance.